# циклический RewritruLe

Tags: mod-rewrite

Захотел сделать URL на кириллице
имеется url

```
http://domain.ru/test/ (существует физически)
```

нужно чтобы было

```
http://domain.ru/тест/
```

правило

```
RewriteRule ^тест/$ /test/ [L,QSA] //замечательно с этим справляется
```

но как дать понять поисковикам, что адрес сменился?
как переправить 301 редиректом?

правило

```
RewriteRule ^test/$ /тест/ [R=301,L] //вызывает цикл
```

подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту дилему?
с помощью meta refresh на странице не хотелось бы :(

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту проблему вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^тест/$ /test/ [E=FINISH:1,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^test/$ /тест/ [E=FINISH:1,R=301,L]
```